# creating index on very large Postgres table is incredibly slow and times out

Tags: postgresql, ssl, indexing, tcp

I have a table with about 200 million rows and 800 columns in an AWS RDS cluster that I'd like to optimize read speed on. Unfortunately, the query creation process is so slow that my client connection times out. I've tried a number of things to address this, such as:

- Modifying the `tcp_keepalive`cluster and timeout settings
- Creating another table and attempting to index that instead
- Adding the `CONCURRENTLY` index creation parameter in case locks were causing delays
- Messing with my local firewall settings so any network connections don't get closed out

In all these cases, after submitting index creation queries, I get an error message after many hours saying: `SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out`

and checking the logs, I see messages like

```
LOG: could not send data to client: Connection timed out
LOG: could not send data to client: Broken pipe
FATAL: connection to client lost
```

I've submitted these queries using Postico and the `psql` CLI in attempt to rule out any weird client settings, too, but to no avail.

I'm a bit of a novice so it's possible I've executed on the troubleshooting steps incorrectly, and I've  also read other related posts to troubleshoot, but haven't really made any headway and would really appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a network problem, not a database problem. Increasing `maintenance_work_mem` and `max_parallel_maintenance_workers` can speed up index creation.

Comment: What if you create an EC2 server, run 'screen' or similar on that to protect your ssh from timing out, and then use 'psql' from there to RDS to run the command?

Comment: What kind of index are you creating?  200 million rows is a lot, but not such an overwhelming number than an ordinary btree index creation should take many hours.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it turns it was a cluster resource issue. I upgraded the RDS instance to a higher RAM/higher vCPU tier and the indices were created relatively quickly. The "Freeable Memory" had plummeted over the past several weeks, so that probably led to some IO bottlenecks and subsequent timeouts.